# Forex spread commission on mini-lots, how does it work?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, commission

Hi guys and sorry if this is a dumb question
So FP-Markets charges the spread as the commission on buying and selling Forex pairs with a full standard lot, my question is if I trade mini lots do I pay the full spread or is it going to be a 10th of the spread?